# How can I write an expression that represents P(X or Y) when....

Tags: probability

a,b,c,d are probabilities
X,Y are events

[image: Venn Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X \cup Y)=\frac{a+b+c}{a+b+c+d}$
if you are looking for only X and only Y, then simply consider a+b

Comment: what about the d

Comment: What I wrote are the favourable cases only. Not to be confused with total probability

Comment: Also if $a,b,c,d$ are probabilities and this is the entire sample space, then $a+b+c+d=1$.